# Can I get off 11.10 and go back to 10.04?

Tags: downgrade, version

I want to go back to an older Ubuntu but when I try to boot from a cd 11.10 somehow overrides and always boots up.
I have tried from cd & usb stick.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you change the boot order priority in the BIOS. It is the only thing that governs which device boots first.